# How to update Currency Symbols dynamically for each fields based on provided Country

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

With this static payload, how will I able to change those currency symbols based on the country provided in the request

```
[
    {
        "orderId": "11111101",
        "details": {
            "TotalPrice": {
                "NetPrice__c": 11.11,
                "NetPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 $"
            },
            "TotalCartValue__c": 11.11,
            "TotalCartValueFormatted__c": "11,11 $",
            "TotalTaxPrice__c": 11.11,
            "TotalTaxPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 $",
            "TotalDiscountPrice__c": 11.11,
            "TotalDiscountPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 $",
            "products": [
                {
                    "SKUNumber__c": "111111-01",
                    "Quantity": "1",
                    "UnitPrice": 11.11,
                    "UnitPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 $",
                    "TotalPrice": 11.11,
                    "TotalPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 $",
                    "Discount__c": 11.11,
                    "DiscountFormatted__c": "11,11 $",
                    "ProductName__c": "Apple",
                    "MachineFriendlyName__c": "iPhone",
                    "DiscountValue__c": 11.11,
                    "bundles": []
                }
            ],
             "shippingModes": [
                "ClickAndCollect",
                "ScheduledDelivery",
                "StandardDelivery"
            ],
            "TotalItems__c": 1,
            "PromoCode__c": null,
            "PromoStatus__c": null
        }
    },
    {
        "orderId": "22222202",
        "details": {
            "TotalPrice": {
                "NetPrice__c": 22.22,
                "NetPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 $"
            },
            "TotalCartValue__c": 22.22,
            "TotalCartValueFormatted__c": "22,22 $",
            "TotalTaxPrice__c": 22.22,
            "TotalTaxPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 $",
            "TotalDiscountPrice__c": 22.22,
            "TotalDiscountPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 $",
            "products": [
                {
                    "SKUNumber__c": "222222-02",
                    "Quantity": "1",
                    "UnitPrice": 22.22,
                    "UnitPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 $",
                    "TotalPrice": 22.22,
                    "TotalPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 $",
                    "Discount__c": 22.22,
                    "DiscountFormatted__c": "22,22 $",
                    "ProductName__c": "Samsung",
                    "MachineFriendlyName__c": "Galaxy",
                    "DiscountValue__c": 22.22,
                    "bundles": []
                }
            ],
             "shippingModes": [
                "ClickAndCollect",
                "ScheduledDelivery",
                "StandardDelivery"
            ],
            "TotalItems__c": 1,
            "PromoCode__c": null,
            "PromoStatus__c": null
        }
    }
]
```

For example, the country in the request is Italy and filtering with orderId of 11111101

the result will be: (same structure of the static payload, only difference is the currency symbols will change)

```
[
    {
        "orderId": "11111101",
        "details": {
            "TotalPrice": {
                "NetPrice__c": 11.11,
                "NetPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 €"
            },
            "TotalCartValue__c": 11.11,
            "TotalCartValueFormatted__c": "11,11 €",
            "TotalTaxPrice__c": 11.11,
            "TotalTaxPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 €",
            "TotalDiscountPrice__c": 11.11,
            "TotalDiscountPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 €",
            "products": [
                {
                    "SKUNumber__c": "111111-01",
                    "Quantity": "1",
                    "UnitPrice": 11.11,
                    "UnitPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 €",
                    "TotalPrice": 11.11,
                    "TotalPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 €",
                    "Discount__c": 11.11,
                    "DiscountFormatted__c": "11,11 €",
                    "ProductName__c": "Apple",
                    "MachineFriendlyName__c": "iPhone",
                    "DiscountValue__c": 11.11,
                    "bundles": []
                }
            ],
             "shippingModes": [
                "ClickAndCollect",
                "ScheduledDelivery",
                "StandardDelivery"
            ],
            "TotalItems__c": 1,
            "PromoCode__c": null,
            "PromoStatus__c": null
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this recursive solution to update each field based on values present on countryNames variable and replace it with your required symbol. You can refer more about [replace](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-replace) here

Dataweave

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var countryNames = {
    "England": "£",
    "Philliphines": "₱"
}
fun replaceDollarWithCountryValue(data: Any, country: String): Any =
    data match {
        case is Array -> data map replaceDollarWithCountryValue($, country)
        case is Object -> $ mapObject ((value, key, index) ->
            (key): replaceDollarWithCountryValue(value, country))
        
        else -> if (($ is String)and($ contains "\$"))
                    $ replace "\$" with countryNames[country] 
                else $
    }
---
replaceDollarWithCountryValue(payload, "England")
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "orderId": "11111101",
    "details": {
      "TotalPrice": {
        "NetPrice__c": 11.11,
        "NetPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 £"
      },
      "TotalCartValue__c": 11.11,
      "TotalCartValueFormatted__c": "11,11 £",
      "TotalTaxPrice__c": 11.11,
      "TotalTaxPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 £",
      "TotalDiscountPrice__c": 11.11,
      "TotalDiscountPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 £",
      "products": [
        {
          "SKUNumber__c": "111111-01",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "UnitPrice": 11.11,
          "UnitPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 £",
          "TotalPrice": 11.11,
          "TotalPriceFormatted__c": "11,11 £",
          "Discount__c": 11.11,
          "DiscountFormatted__c": "11,11 £",
          "ProductName__c": "Apple",
          "MachineFriendlyName__c": "iPhone",
          "DiscountValue__c": 11.11,
          "bundles": [
            
          ]
        }
      ],
      "shippingModes": [
        "ClickAndCollect",
        "ScheduledDelivery",
        "StandardDelivery"
      ],
      "TotalItems__c": 1,
      "PromoCode__c": null,
      "PromoStatus__c": null
    }
  },
  {
    "orderId": "22222202",
    "details": {
      "TotalPrice": {
        "NetPrice__c": 22.22,
        "NetPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 £"
      },
      "TotalCartValue__c": 22.22,
      "TotalCartValueFormatted__c": "22,22 £",
      "TotalTaxPrice__c": 22.22,
      "TotalTaxPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 £",
      "TotalDiscountPrice__c": 22.22,
      "TotalDiscountPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 £",
      "products": [
        {
          "SKUNumber__c": "222222-02",
          "Quantity": "1",
          "UnitPrice": 22.22,
          "UnitPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 £",
          "TotalPrice": 22.22,
          "TotalPriceFormatted__c": "22,22 £",
          "Discount__c": 22.22,
          "DiscountFormatted__c": "22,22 £",
          "ProductName__c": "Samsung",
          "MachineFriendlyName__c": "Galaxy",
          "DiscountValue__c": 22.22,
          "bundles": [
            
          ]
        }
      ],
      "shippingModes": [
        "ClickAndCollect",
        "ScheduledDelivery",
        "StandardDelivery"
      ],
      "TotalItems__c": 1,
      "PromoCode__c": null,
      "PromoStatus__c": null
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is Perfect! Thank you Karthik